# iOS: Badge refuses to update (appcelerator)

Tags: ios, push-notification, titanium, appcelerator, badge

I've developed an app and everything works fine except updating the badge **when the app is not running**.

I receive the push notification but nothing happens with the badge.

The application request the alert and badge type when registering with Apple.

Any ideas? This is driving me crazy.

This is the code I use to send the push:

```
<?php
$apnsHost = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com';
$apnsCert = '/usr/local/php/cert.pem';
$apnsPort = 2195;

$streamContext = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);

$apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apnsHost . ':' . $apnsPort, $error, $errorString, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);

$payload['aps'] = array('alert' => 'Oh hai!', 'badge' => 1);
$output = json_encode($payload);
$token = '1234';
$token = pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $token));
$apnsMessage = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . $token . chr(0) . chr(strlen($output)) . $output;
fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage);

socket_close($apns);
fclose($apns);
```

Comment: Could you show us the mobile side code?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the following

1. [Newsstand Module](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Modules.Newsstand).
2. [applicationIconBadgeNumber property](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Modules.Newsstand-property-applicationIconBadgeNumber)
3. [getApplicationIconBadgeNumber() method](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Modules.Newsstand-method-getApplicationIconBadgeNumber)
4. [setApplicationIconBadgeNumber() method](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Modules.Newsstand-method-setApplicationIconBadgeNumber)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example which uses push and app badge but as i already said you have to show me your mobile side code too if it does not solve your problem.Here is the code

```
    Titanium.Network.registerForPushNotifications({  
   types: [  
     Titanium.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_BADGE,  
     Titanium.Network.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_ALERT  
   ],  
   success:function(e)  
   {  
     var deviceToken = e.deviceToken;  
     Ti.API.info("Push notification device token is: "+deviceToken);  
     alert('device token is' +e.deviceToken);  
     Ti.API.info("Push notification types: "+Titanium.Network.remoteNotificationTypes);  
     Ti.API.info("Push notification enabled: "+Titanium.Network.remoteNotificationsEnabled);  
   },  
   error:function(e)  
   {  
     Ti.API.info("Error during registration: "+e.error);  
   },  
   callback:function(e)  
   {  
     // called when a push notification is received.  
    //Titanium.Media.vibrate();  
    var data = JSON.parse(e.data);  
    var badge = data.badge;  
    if(badge > 0){  
     Titanium.UI.iPhone.appBadge = badge;  
    }  
    var message = data.message;  
    if(message != ''){  
     var my_alert = Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({title:'', message:message});  
     my_alert.show();  
    }  
   }  
  });   
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: Does the app actually run any code when it's turned off? As far as I understood the OS should deal with badges when the app is not running?

Comment: NO it does not run code but it does this in callback function

Comment: So, if that is the case, then the source code won't matter? The question is how the badge can be updated when the app is not running?

Comment: Look at the example above i am updating it in the callback function.You should do the same way for updation

Comment: I understand that concept, but will that code actually run if the application is turned off and the user does not click the notification?